# What are the Odds of Receiving a "Mystery Decal" in a Crate?

Tags: ps4, rocket-league

Each item within a crate has been designated with a certain rarity, with the "Mystery Decal" being the rarest object within a crate.

**What are the odds of receiving this item in a crate? Does it vary between the different types of crates? (Ex. Player's Choice vs. Turbo)**

[image: Mystery Decal]

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/RocketLeagueExchange/comments/52u01d/meta_by_the_numbers_crate_opening_odds_and_the/ although this isn't bullet proof.  Most seem to agree with it though or at least think they are reasonable.

Comment: @TimmyJim Thanks, took a look at this one, but I wasn't sure how accurate it was. Might post this as an answer if nothing else comes to light.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The drop chance for Black Market decals is the same across all crates.

Psyonix has not released any official rates so the exact drop rate is unknown. There has been some analysis of crate openings done and the speculation is that the BM chances are between 1-2%. The analyses below have determined a rate of 1.2% and 1.4% respectively so 1-2% is a fair estimate. Best of luck opening crates if you go down that route!

Sources:

- [Reddit 1](https://www.reddit.com/r/RocketLeague/comments/54b6zp/hey_rrocket_league_ive_watched_300_crate_openings/)
- [Reddit 2](https://www.reddit.com/r/RocketLeague/comments/5j2nkg/rocket_league_crate_odds_in_depth_discussion_by/)